# What determines the maximum number of concurrent users of a SAS stored process server?

Tags: sas

I have heard that the number of logical stored process servers is the maximum number of users that can run stored processes concurrently. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost true.

The number of logical stored process servers is the maximum number of stored processes that can run concurrently. One user can run multiple stored process at the same time. When a stored process has finished running, the server becomes available for all users again.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly driven by the number of multibridge connections (ports) available.  In a default config there are only three - but it is [recommended](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/378-2012.pdf) to have four or five per CPU core.